# How to fix hacked OpenX server?

Tags: security, openx

A client of mine has had his OpenX ad server hacked.

This is the issue, there are 4 ads in a vertical stack, the 3rd one is hijacked and replaced by a different ad, a sky ad.

I've tried searching the entire database including all prepend and append fields for various strings, even the smallest strings that could identify the source of the hack. I've done grep searches of the entire ad server directory, and even the entire website, every file type, everything.

I can't even upgrade the ad server, it doesn't seem to fix the issue, I've tried, and doing stuff like that's really awkward, doing it remotely via RDP.

Here's a screenshot,

[image]

Also, [here's](http://auctionnews.co.uk) the website.

If anyone doesn't mind taking a look, if you see the "sky" and on the right column, or any animated ad that doesn't quite match the size, border formatting, that's the hacked ad. If it disappears after a couple of refreshes, you need to delete cookies and it should reappear.

If anyone has any other ideas, I'd appreciate it very much.

Comment: Is it resolved? I looked at the site. Not sure which ad was replaced.

Comment: Hi, no it's not resolved. The ad is shown here. It doesn't appear all the time, delete any domain cookies if it disappears. http://filequake.com/cap.png It's the ads that aren't related to auctions, all normal ads are, and will have a small blue border. It's pretty easy to spot. Also, normal ads are never animated, hacked ads are animated. Thanks for looking.

Comment: Is this still an issue?  Looked around the site quite a bit, dumped cookies, never saw the 'sky' or any other animated ad other than the auction related ads.  Can you provide more info? Did you discover the hacked ad yourself?  Has anyone else seen the hacked ad?

Comment: Can you post the html source that comes up in your browser when you render the page. I can't see the ad. If I had to guess, there is a line of javascript inserting the ad and as a result grep does not find it. I

Comment: Hi, All. It was still an issue until yesterday... It turned out to be a setting deep inside an advertiser's configuration which in previous versions was unchecked by default, this version it is checked by default. The checkbox substitutes your own ads with openx market ads if the payment per click is higher. We've unchecked the box and it's fixed. *huge facepalm*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a setting deep inside an advertiser's configuration which in previous versions was unchecked by default, this version it is checked by default. The checkbox substitutes your own ads with openx market ads if the payment per click is higher. We've unchecked the box and it's fixed.